Problem with .htaccess redirection to my API
I have a WordPress site in which I develop a plugin. Inside this plugin, I developed a API.
In my local environment, my URL to access my site is http://localhost:81/site. I'd like requests made to http://localhost:81/site/api, like http://localhost:81/site/api/authentication/login to be redirected to http://localhost:81/site/wp-content/plugins/my_plugin/api/routes.php. I have this rule in my .htaccess:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/site/api/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/site/api/(.*)$ /site/wp-content/plugins/my_plugin/api/rotas.php [QSA,L]

But it's not working. checking my error.log, I've noticed the following line when I tried to make a request:
(...) [rewrite:trace3] (...) [perdir C:/myproject/site/] applying pattern '^/site/api/(.*)$' to uri 'api/authentication/login'

It seems that the rule is searching for /site/api, while the "input string" is comparing for is "/api/authentication", so i changed my .htacess to this:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^api/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ /site/wp-content/plugins/my_plugin/api/rotas.php [QSA,L]

And this is the log I get:
(...) [perdir C:/myproject/site/] applying pattern '^api/(.*)$' to uri 'api/authentication/login'
(...) [perdir C:/myproject/site/] RewriteCond: input='/site/api/authentication/login' pattern='^api/' [NC] => not-matched

The first line indicates its now searching with the right strings, and the second line was showing before, and now is, but its comparing with /site/api
Why in the first comparison is it removing the /site prefix and in the second it's not?
This seems to be happening earlier in the log file:
[perdir C:/myproject/site/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/myproject/site/api/authentication/login -> api/authentication/login


Don't try to roll your own API on top of Wordpress. They already have one. You should register your own custom endpoints instead

The issue is your RewriteRule, not the RewriteCond:
the documentation clearly states (and all examples here on SO show this), that the pattern in a RewriteRule is applied to the relative path of the request, so without leading slash, as long as the rule is implemented in a distributed configuration file (".htaccess"). As opposed to when the rule is implemented in the central configuration, where it is matched against an absolut path. RewriteCond patterns are always matched against an absolut path.
In addition your condition is not required at all. The rule itself is perfectly capable of matching the requested path, so keep things simple:
RewriteRule ^site/api/(.*)$ /site/wp-content/plugins/my_plugin/api/rotas.php [QSA,L]

You can easily write a rule with a pattern that matches in both forms of implementation: just make the leading slash optional:
RewriteRule ^/?site/api/(.*)$ /site/wp-content/plugins/my_plugin/api/rotas.php [QSA,L]

If you want to continue to use a distributed configuration file (so a ".htaccess" file inside the content area of of your http host), then above form of the rule needs to be implemented in a file located inside the http hosts DocumentRoot folder, not somewhere further down. Otherwise your pattern would not get applied against the full requested path, if at all. Again, see the documentation for details.
So in case you want to implement this in side a configuration file inside the site folder of your http host's file system part (if such folder actually exists, which I doubt), then you'd have to adapt the rule like that:
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ /site/wp-content/plugins/my_plugin/api/rotas.php [QSA,L]

Or even like that to keep it completely relative:
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ wp-content/plugins/my_plugin/api/rotas.php [QSA,L]

